# How to do an Update from a Select in Azure?

Tags: sql-update, azure-sql-database

I need to update a second table with the results of this query:

```
SELECT Tag, battery, Wearlevel, SensorTime 
FROM ( 
SELECT m.* , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TAG ORDER BY SensorTime DESC) AS rn 
FROM [dbo].[TELE] m  
) m2 
where m2.rn = 1;
```

But. I had a hard time fixing the SET  without messing it up. I want to have a table which has all data from last date of each TAG without duplicates.

Comment: If you need further help, pls let me know.

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code maybe you want.

[image]

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.Primarykey = 'ss'+Table_B.Primarykey,
    Table_A.AddTime = 'jason_'+Table_B.AddTime
FROM
    Test AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN UsersInfo AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.id = Table_B.id
WHERE
    Table_A.Primarykey = '559713e6-0d85-4fe7-87a4-e9ceb22abdcf'
```

**For more details, you also can refer below posts and blogs.**

[1. How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server)

[2. How to UPDATE from SELECT in SQL Server](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-update-from-select-in-sql-server/)